# PhoneGap/Android: Google Map not fully displayed in emulator

Tags: javascript, android, google-maps, cordova, android-emulator

I'm trying to get a PhoneGap application for Android running (using Eclipse with PhoneGap for Andoroid plugin) featuring a Google Map. Essentially it seems to work. However, there some glitches when displaying the map. I have no phone at hand, only the emulator. The map looks, for example, like the picture below:

[image]

The controls and this 'Terms of Use' are all there, but there are parts missing from the map. When I move the map it slides also empty/grey areas. But after refreshing/reloading, parts of the map vanish again. And it's not always the same area, sometimes smaller, sometimes a bit larger. But never the full area is filled with the map.

Is this an error/glitch of the emulator. When searching for problems I only stumble upon the issue that the map is not displayed at all (e.g., layout is 0px/0px or the API key is missing). I also have a native Android application, and there die Activity with a Google Map is displayed quite fine.

Thanks for any hints!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok, after some more searching the Web, I've found the problem. It seems to be a common issue when you try to load a map in a hidden DIV element. The trick is to simply refresh the map after this DIV becomes visible. One way I found and that worked for me is to mnually trigger the resize event: `google.maps.event.trigger(map, "resize");`

Comment: I am having the same issue,but i cant understood your answer,can you please explain?

Comment: Not really much to explain. At some the DIV becomes visible, for example, after calling `$("#myDivId").show();`. After that, you just have to call `google.maps.event.trigger(map, "resize");`, where `map` is your handle to the map which initialized at the start, for example `var map = new google.maps.Map($("#map_canvas").get(0), { center: {lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644}, zoom: 8 });`

Comment: But i am using <map> tag for displaying map,and other thing is my issue is when first time i come to page goole map loaded perfectly,but go to another page and back again then map is broken,never loaded.

Comment: Hey,please help me brother.:(

Comment: Hard to say what to do without seeing the code. You might want to open a new question and providing the core snippets. Just some comments: Firstly, the `<map>` has nothing to do with displaying Google Maps; that's for creating image maps. It probably doesn't hurt to place a Google Map into `<map>` though. Secondly, what do you mean by "go to another page"? A complete different website? A different page of your own site? If the latter, do you load complete new pages or do you change the content by hiding/showing DIVs? I recommend opening a new question and providing details.

Comment: Yes i am clearing your doubts,I have an app which is using onsen io framework,it comes with inbuild back button and it also maintains a pagestack,So let say we are having a two page app,on page1 we are having a map and one second nothing,when we go to second page and return to first by back button,the map on page1 broken up.now hope you understood my point..please help

Answer (score 1):

Could you post your code? When I had an issue like this I applied this to the container that was holding the map:

```
layout: {
   type: 'fit'
}
```

Comment: Thanks for you help! I found the problem; see my answer. I missed the essential point that I initially load the map in a hidden DIV.